# How to call action in ajax?

Tags: controllers, ajax

My controller Save in

```
app/code/local/Management/Task/controllers/Adminhtml/TaskController.php
action name:save
```

in phtml code:

```
  url: '<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('management/adminhtml/orderattachments/save')?>'
```

this my magento url:
                   127.0.0.1/magento19/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/1/key/7e4f7e7863c2844b08e421c6e866a718/

in network XHR 404 error accours.
what is wrong in url?

Answer (score 1):

Change url

```
<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/view/orderattachments/save')?>
```

Comment: is it works?....

Comment: Please accept your answer and it will complete the thread